# Is there anything wrong with this sentence? the pages stopped flipping and all of it were blank,

Tags: grammar, writing

I need to describe that I was looking at a book flipping by the wind and when it stopped all the pages were blank so is there something wrong in this sentence:

> The pages stopped flipping and all of it were blank.

Comment: Perhaps "them" instead of it, after all the pages are plural and you've correctly pluralised were.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, there is a problem with the sentence.

You've got an issue with agreement:

- "pages" is in plural
- "it" is singular
- "were" is plural.

So you would have to change "it" into plural.

"The pages stopped flipping and all of them were blank."

Comment: Or "all of it was blank" would work equally well, "it" in this context referring to the book.

Comment: I thought about that, @PrimeMover, but decided against suggesting it as "the pages stopped flipping, and all of it was blank" seemed weird without explicit inclusion of the word "book" in the preceding clause.